# How to put WindowManager content behind navigation bar

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I am developing an Android app that looks like Facebook Messenger chat head. There's a view that goes above all other apps. You can press it and drag it wherever you want on the screen.

It works pretty well so far, I just have one problem: I'd like my view to go under the bottom navigation bar, when the user drags it partially outside of the screen. Now, the view is always above the navigation bar.

Here is how I set up this view:

```
View myView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.my_view, null);
myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
int screenHeight = Utils.getScreenHeight(this);

windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_ATTACHED_IN_DECOR
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;

windowManager.addView(myView, params);
```

On forums, I can only see people complaining about that fact their view goes behind the navigation bar whereas they want it to go above so I'm kind of thinking I'm doing something really wrong here.

Comment: Any update on this ? Putting content behind navigation bar is different from WindowManager and Activity. I am facing the same problem

Comment: Nope, couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

You certainly shouldn't use `FLAG_LAYOUT_ATTACHED_IN_DECOR`. Don't know about `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` though. Without first flag I have popup appearing under navigation bar with conjuction of `windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds=true` in theme.

Also to easilty test it, set height to `match_parent`